# Combining multikey index with single field index in Mongodb C# yields unexpected results

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql

Given that I have the following data structure in MongoDB:

```
public class Chat 
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; init; }
    public string ExternalId { get; init; }
    public ICollection<string> ParticipantIds { get; init; }
}
```

and having 2 documents in the database as follows:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("604fd41cb86313a7d8c0dc91"),
   "ExternalId" : "1",
   "ParticipantIds" : [ 
       "a", 
       "b"
   ]
},
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("604fd41cb86313a7d8c0dc92"),
   "ExternalId" : "1",
   "ParticipantIds" : [ 
       "a", 
       "c"
   ]
}
```

... and then applying the following indexes

```
var participantIdsAndExternalIdCompoundIndex = new CreateIndexModel<ChatData>(Builders<ChatData>.IndexKeys.Combine(
            Builders<ChatData>.IndexKeys.Ascending(chat => chat.ExternalId),
            Builders<ChatData>.IndexKeys.Ascending(chat => chat.ParticipantIds)
            ), new CreateIndexOptions { Unique = true });
        
        Collection.Indexes.CreateMany(new[] { participantIdsAndExternalIdCompoundIndex });

// The shell version
db.getCollection('chats').createIndex({ExternalId: 1, ParticipantIds: 1}, {unique: true})
```

I would expect the index to be created without any issues since the combination of ExternalId and ParticipantIds is unique. However, I get the following exception telling me that at any one value of the ParticipantIds array existing in another document combined with an existing ExternalId violates the uniqueness.
I have also ran the equivalent in the shell which yields the same result:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: messageServiceDb.chats index: ExternalId_1_ParticipantIds_1 dup key: { : "1", : "a" }
```

So my question is; Is this expected behavior? If so, is there another way of using indexes in MongoDB to accomplish the same behavior?

Comment: @Llama There are none.

Comment: /* 1 */
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "messageServiceDb.chats"
    }
]
@Llama

Comment: No it is not. In my questions I'm saying that I cannot create the index due to the error. @Llama

Comment: That is exactly what I have already written in my question.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) state _"To index a field that holds an array value, **MongoDB creates an index key for each element in the array.**"_, so I would expect index keys 1/A and 1/B to be created for the first object, and 1/A and 1/C for the second. While it's possible to have duplicate index keys in a single document, duplicate index keys aren't possible between documents with the unique constraint. It's therefore expected behaviour. Perhaps an additional field that combines id/participant ids with a unique index on it would help.

Comment: I think you are right, however the documentation is not crystal clear on the behavior. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score -2):

When you index an array field, you can think of the values in the array being exploded into individual documents and then those documents are independently indexed (the values are added to the index separately but all of the index entries point to the original document).

So, in your example the indexed data would be

```
(1, a) -> ...91*
(1, b) -> ...91

(1, a) -> ...92 *
(1, c) -> ...92
```

The two entries marked with the asterisk conflict.